# macOSでSwiftUIを使ってWKWebViewを表示したい

Tags: macos, swiftui, webkit

`iOS`のサンプルは沢山あるのですが、`macOS`のサンプルがなく、流用してみても画面が真っ白で、指定した`URL`のサイトが表示されません。どなたか、ご教示よろしくお願いします。

`WebView.swift`

```swift
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView: NSViewRepresentable {
    let url = "https://google.com"

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        nsView.load(request)
    }
}

struct WebView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WebView()
    }
}
```

`ContentView.swift`

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        WebView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SandBoxで、`outgoing connections`にチェックが入っていないだけでした